# how to set validators and custom validators in angular 14 ngForms

Tags: angular

I'm using ngForms and I want to add validators.required and some custom validators. All solutions I found are using formGroup builder, is this the only way? I don't want to use it as it's complicated with multiple-option select.
I tried this but it didn't work
TS file

```
  onFormSubmit(form:NgForm){
  this.formSubmitted = true;
  form.controls['title'].addValidators([Validators.required])
  form.controls['stageIds'].addValidators([ValidateSelect])


   let newSubject:subject=new subject();
   newSubject.title=form.controls['title'].value;
   newSubject.stageIds=form.controls['stageIds'].value ;
   newSubject.isActive=form.controls['isActive'].value;
   console.log(newSubject)
   this.subjectService.addSubject(newSubject).subscribe(res=>{
    if (res.status == 1)
            this.route.navigateByUrl('subjects');
   })


  }
```

in html I add span to reflect the error before sending request but it's also not working

```
<form  #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(form)" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3>إضافة بيانات مادة جديدة</h3>
                    <div class="row mb-3">
                        <div class="col-6 gx-5">
                            <div class="row">
                                <label for="example-text-input" class=" col-form-label"> اسم المادة</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="title" type="text"
                                [ngModel]="" #title="ngModel"
                                    placeholder="اسم المادة" />
                                <span class="errorVal"
                                    *ngIf="formSubmitted && form.controls['title'].hasError('required')">حقل
                                    مطلوب</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-6 gx-5">
                            <div class="row">
                                <label for="example-text-input" class=" col-form-label"> تفعيل </label>
                                <div class="form-check form-switch">
                                    <input 
                                     name="isActive"
                                      class="form-check-input custom-control-input"
                                      type="checkbox"
                                      [ngModel]="false"
                                      #isActive="ngModel"
                                    />
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="row mb-3">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">المراحل
                                    التعليمية</label>
                                <select multiple #stageIds="ngModel"  name="stageIds" [ngModel]="stages"  class="form-select">
                                    <option *ngFor="let item of stages" [ngValue]="item.id">{{item.title}}</option>
                                </select>
                                <span class="errorVal"
                                    *ngIf="formSubmitted && form.controls['stageIds'].hasError('requiredSelect')">
                                    حقل مطلوب
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                        <div class="button-items mt-3">
                            <button 
                                class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light">
                                حفظ
                            </button>
                            <button 
                                class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light">
                                إلغاء
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end col -->
        </div>
        <!-- end row -->
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As template-driven forms don't have the inbuilt capability to provide custom validators, that's why we use ReactiveForms, however, if you had to use the template-driven form with custom validation/validators, you can do this make you own set of directives to and interfaces to achieve that
[Here's a complete blog that teaches how to](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/custom-validator-in-template-driven-forms-in-angular/)